# How to scrape a various amount of <p> in between a <div> class

Tags: html, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape a webpage, which have an unknown amount of < p> tags, in between a known div class.. Some pages have only 1 < p> tag, while others have 10 or even more.. How can I extract them all? Preferable inside one variable, so I can store them inside a csv like all the other data's I'm scraping :)

The HTML structure is as in the following example:

```html
<div class="div_name">
    <h2 class="h5">title text</h2>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>text text text...</p>
    <p>text text text...</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p><br>text text text...</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p><br>text text text...</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p><br>text text text...</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p><br>text text text...</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>text text text...</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p><br>text text text...</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p><br>text text text...</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p><br>text text text...</p>
    <p>text text text...</p>
    <p>text text text...</p>
</div>
```

I'm using python and scrapy framework to achieve this.

Currently I have:

```
divs = response.xpath('/html/body/div[6]/div/section[2]/article/div/div/div')
for p in divs.xpath('.//p'):  # extracts all <p> inside
        print(p.get())
story = p

yield {
    'story': story
    }
```

It does print all the text values for the various < p> tags, but when stored to the csv file, only the last < p> is inserted to the *.csv.

To store the scraped data into *.csv, I have the following inside my settings.py:

```
# Deph of Crawler
DEPTH_LIMIT = 0 # 0 = Infinite depth

# Feed Export Settings
FEED_FORMAT="csv"
FEED_URI="output_%(name)s.csv"
```

and the *yield* part above, are the fields going into the *.csv.

Kindest regards,

Comment: Hi, can you share code snippet used to insert data in csv?

Comment: Edited my post to share the way I save to *.csv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it in one line, really:

```
story = ' '.join([x.get().strip() for x in response.xpath('//div[6]/div/section[2]/article/div/div/div//p')])
```

If you would confirm the page url, I would probably be able to improve that long, fragile XPATH. Nonetheless, the above should work.

Scrapy documentation can be found at https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/

Comment: Thanks! This is working even better than the other solution provided, as this will remove the whitespace <p > tags, which some have a lot! I had been looking into the scrapy documentation, which is where I found the used code snippet. Thanks for the help. Marked as solution!

Answer (score 0):

You have to store the text of all the p tags and then join them using space or line-break or whatever you want and then assign to story variable.

```
divs = response.xpath('/html/body/div[6]/div/section[2]/article/div/div/div')
arr = [] # this will store the text of all p tags 
for p in divs.xpath('.//p'):  # extracts all <p> inside
        print(p.get())
        arr.append(p.get()) 
story = '\n'.join(arr)

yield {
    'story': story
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a million! Working like a charm! Now I can move on and find a way to have the characters fixed (scraping from a PT website, which has a lot of special characters heheh). Have a great day Mohsin!

Comment: You're welcome and thanks for the appreciation. I'm glad I could help. Have a great day too!